# Implementing Jira Oauth using .net or DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth, jira-rest-api

I am trying to implement Jira Oauth using DotNetOpenAuth. My problem is

ServiceProviderDescription RsaSha1ConsumerSigningBindingElement which accepts X509Certificate2 but Jira uses RSA (a .pem file as private key not a pfx file).

None of examples in DotNetOpenAuth uses Private key. I am now confused how can I create a Jira Consumer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see my answer here:

[Loading the Jira Public Certificate in .Net from a string (how to convert ASN.1 encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo to X509 Cert in .Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493722/loading-the-jira-public-certificate-in-net-from-a-string-how-to-convert-asn-1/19159873#19159873)

I used DotNetAuth (not DotNetOpenAuth) for this purpose with success.

Hope this helps.